# Lambda(->) to Double colon(::) method reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

here I'm trying to print values using lambda. Is it possible to make it in double colon way?

```
public class Occurance 
{
    static void occuranceUsingListSet()
    {
        ArrayList<String> listColors = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Red","blue","green","green"));
        Set<String> setVals = new LinkedHashSet<>(listColors);
        setVals.stream().forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + " : " + Collections.frequency(listColors, s)));
    }
    
}
```

`setVals.stream().forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + " : " + Collections.frequency(listColors, s)));`

Is there any possibilities to use double colon?

And is method reference and pass by reference are same?

I can see this  double colon is pass method reference.
But in this slack answer I can see that there is no such thing like pass by reference in java.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73021/11962586.

Comment: The answer depends on how willing you are to restructure the code. One idea that comes to my mind would be to forego the explicit frequency calculation, and collect to a map instead, calculating the frequency implicitly through the merge function. [`ideone.com` demo](https://ideone.com/jbzeky)

Comment: _Method reference_ and _pass by reference_ are two completely different concepts. They have nothing to do with each other. By the way: Java is _pass by value_, always (and not pass by reference).

Comment: Why copy as a set? It can be just `listColors.stream().map(s -> s + " : " + Collections.frequency(listColors, s)).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: @DuncG, but we are getting output two times. like ```Red : 1
blue : 1
green : 2
green : 2```

Comment: @S14321K Oops, ignore me

Comment: @DuncG haha, no problem. Your  soulution worked great. Though I found another solution.  ```listColors.stream().map(s -> s + " : " + Collections.frequency(listColors, s)).distinct().forEach(System.out::println);``` Adding distinct() done the job great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot do that whole operation with a single method reference. You are doing more than a single method call in your lambda.

Although, if you refactor your string creation into a new function, then you can use a method reference to call `System.out.println`:

```java
static void occuranceUsingListSet() {
    // You don't need to wrap Arrays.asList in a new ArrayList.
    List<String> listColors = Arrays.asList("Red","blue","green","green");
    Set<String> setVals = new LinkedHashSet<>(listColors);

    setVals.stream()
        .map(s -> createFrequencyString(s, listColors);
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}

static String createFrequencyString(String color, List<String> colors) {
    return color + " : " + Collections.frequency(colors, color);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is method reference and pass by reference are same? I need some clarity in that too. I edited the question. Thanks

Comment: No, those are difference things. Java does not have pass by reference, only pass by value. a method reference is just a syntactic way to refer to a method instead of writing out the lambda expression.

Answer (score 1):

With a little reworking of the method you can use a method reference.  Since you didn't specify if a `set` was required, I am using a `map` as it offers some efficiencies.

```
List<String> listColors = Arrays.asList("Red", "blue", "green",
        "green");
```

I am calling the method `printOccurrences` since that is what you are doing.  It takes a `Supplier<Stream<String>>` as the parameter.  The stream is obtained in the method by using `get()`.

```
printOccurrences(listColors::stream);
```

prints

```
Red : 1, blue : 1, green : 2
```

Using `Collections.frequency` is ill advised since you must traverse the entire list for each specified object.  Using a `Map` to compute frequencies is a more common technique as it does it in a single pass over the list. For each color string, [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.stream.Collector)) along with [Collectors.counting](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting()) will compute the frequency for each map entry pair of `<String, Long>`.  The entries are then streamed to obtain the collected data and [joined](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining(java.lang.CharSequence))into a string for printing (the format of which can be altered as required).  I used a `LinkedHashMap` supplier to preserve the order of colors as they are processed. If not required or desired, it can be removed.

So in order

- get the stream and compute the frequencies using `groupingBy`
- then stream the entry set, extracting the key(color String) and value(frequency) and format for joining.  I am joining each pair with `", "`.
- all of the above is then passed to `System.out.println`.

```
static void printOccurrences(Supplier<Stream<String>> stream) {
     System.out.println(stream.get()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(color -> color,
                     LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
             .entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.getKey() + " : " + e.getValue())
             .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
}
```

Some final notes.

- The method above can also be easily altered to return the string for printing and/or take the list as an argument and just stream it there without using a Supplier.
- Unless you want `"Red"` to be different than `"red"` you should convert to a common case, otherwise they will be treated as different colors. For something like this, title case might be a nice choice so it can be done as follows:

```
static String toTitleCase(String str) {
     return str.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

Then change `a -> a` in `groupingBy` to `a->toTitleCase(a)`